# How to parse unconventional XML files

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have the need to take what I consider an "unconventional" XML file that I get in and convert it into what I consider "conventional". The below XML examples have been "scrubbed" of proprietary names/values.

Here is what the "unconventional" XML file looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <dataView name="document/aDocument" xmlns="http://component.mycompany.com/entity/ds" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <dataItems>
        <dataItem name="item1" location="item1" dataItemType="Long">
            <value xsi:type="xs:string">1</value>
        </dataItem>
        <dataItem name="item2" location="item.seconditem(some item).ref" dataItemType="String">
            <value xsi:type="xs:string">ABC2DEF3</value>
        </dataItem>
    </dataItems>
    <dataRepeaters>
        <dataRepeater name="SomeLevel1" runtimeInfomration="SomeLevel11984371030">
            <dataGroups>
                <dataGroup name="SomeLevel2" location="SomeLevel:(a level).thelevel" keyValue="SomeLevel119843710300" runtimeInformation="19843710300">
                    <dataItems>
                        <dataItem name="someItem1" location="someLevel.aLevel(another item)" dataItemType="String">
                            <value xsi:type="xs:string">12345</value>
                        </dataItem>
                        <dataItem name="someItem2" location="someLevel.aLevel(another item2)" dataItemType="Integer"/>
                        <dataItem name="someItem3" location="someLevel.aLevel(another item3)" dataItemType="ObjectReference">
                            <value xsi:type="xs:string">11:20012:3536</value>
                        </dataItem>
                        <dataItem name="someItem4" location="someLevel.aLevel(another item4)" dataItemType="String"/>
                        <dataItem name="someItem5" location="someLevel.aLevel(another item5)" dataItemType="String">
                            <value xsi:type="xs:string">someItem5 Data</value>
                        </dataItem>
                        <dataItem name="someItem6" location="someLevel.aLevel(another item6)" dataItemType="CurrencyAmount">
                            <value xsi:type="xs:string">123456:USD</value>
                        </dataItem>
                    </dataItems>
                </dataGroup>
                <dataGroup name="SomeLevel3" keyValue="SomeLevel31984371030" runtimeInformation="1984371030">
                    <dataRepeaters>
                        <dataRepeater name="SomeLevel4" runtimeInfomration="SomeLevel4">
                            <dataGroups>
                                <dataGroup name="SomeLevel5" location="anotherLevel.level5(SomeLevel5):someLevel5" keyValue="SomeLevel51984371030-11521863690" runtimeInformation="1984371030-11521863690">
                                    <dataItems>
                                        <dataItem name="someItem6" location="someLevel.aLevel(another item6)" dataItemType="BigDecimal">
                                            <value xsi:type="xs:string">303.149</value>
                                        </dataItem>
                                        <dataItem name="someItem7" location="someLevel.aLevel(another item7)" dataItemType="CurrencyAmount">
                                            <value xsi:type="xs:string">117:USD</value>
                                        </dataItem>
                                        <dataItem name="someItem8" location="someLevel.aLevel(another item8)" dataItemType="String">
                                            <value xsi:type="xs:string">117.000000:USD</value>
                                        </dataItem>
                                        <dataItem name="someItem9" location="someLevel.aLevel(another item9)" dataItemType="CurrencyAmount">
                                            <value xsi:type="xs:string">117:USD</value>
                                        </dataItem>
                                    </dataItems>
                                    <dataRepeaters>
                                        <dataRepeater name="SomeLevel6" runtimeInfomration="someLevel6">
                                            <dataGroups/>
                                            </dataRepeater>
                                    </dataRepeaters>
                                </dataGroup>
                                <dataGroup name="SomeLevel7" location="anotherLevel.level5(SomeLevel7):someLevel7" keyValue="SomeLevel71984371030-11521863690" runtimeInformation="1984371030-11521863690">
                                    <dataItems>
                                        <dataItem name="someItem10" location="someLevel.aLevel(another item10)" dataItemType="BigDecimal">
                                            <value xsi:type="xs:string">292.741</value>
                                        </dataItem>
                                        <dataItem name="someItem11" location="someLevel.aLevel(another item11)" dataItemType="CurrencyAmount">
                                            <value xsi:type="xs:string">165:USD</value>
                                        </dataItem>
                                        <dataItem name="someItem12" location="someLevel.aLevel(another item12)" dataItemType="String">
                                            <value xsi:type="xs:string">165.000000:USD</value>
                                        </dataItem>
                                        <dataItem name="someItem13" location="someLevel.aLevel(another item13)" dataItemType="CurrencyAmount">
                                            <value xsi:type="xs:string">165:USD</value>
                                        </dataItem>
                                    </dataItems>
                                    <dataRepeaters/>
                                </dataGroup>
                                <dataGroup name="SomeLevel8" location="anotherLevel.level5(SomeLevel8):someLevel8" keyValue="SomeLevel81984371030-11521863690" runtimeInformation="1984371030-11521863690">
                                    <dataItems>
                                        <dataItem name="someItem14" location="someLevel.aLevel(another item14)" dataItemType="BigDecimal">
                                            <value xsi:type="xs:string">369.075</value>
                                        </dataItem>
                                        <dataItem name="someItem15" location="someLevel.aLevel(another item15)" dataItemType="CurrencyAmount">
                                            <value xsi:type="xs:string">598:USD</value>
                                        </dataItem>
                                        <dataItem name="someItem16" location="someLevel.aLevel(another item16)" dataItemType="String">
                                            <value xsi:type="xs:string">598.000000:USD</value>
                                        </dataItem>
                                    </dataItems>
                                    <dataRepeaters>
                                        <dataRepeater name="SomeLevel9" runtimeInfomration="someLevel9">
                                            <dataGroups>
                                                <dataGroup name="SomeLevel10" location="ownedAuto.AgreementActual(Liability).ConstantRole(Policy Form):policyForm" keyValue="aomeLevel101984371030-11521863690-115218636900" runtimeInformation="1984371030-11521863690-115218636900">
                                                    <dataItems>
                                                        <dataItem name="someItem17" location="someLevel.aLevel(another item17)" dataItemType="String">
                                                            <value xsi:type="xs:string">Some Data | ABC 123</value>
                                                        </dataItem>
                                                        <dataItem name="someItem18" location="someLevel.aLevel(another item18)" dataItemType="Integer">
                                                            <value xsi:type="xs:string">2</value>
                                                        </dataItem>
                                                    </dataItems>
                                                </dataGroup>
                                            </dataGroups>
                                        </dataRepeater>
                                        <dataRepeater name="SomeLevel10" runtimeInfomration="someLevel11">
                                            <dataGroups/>
                                        </dataRepeater>
                                    </dataRepeaters>
                                </dataGroup>
                            </dataGroups>
                        </dataRepeater>
                    </dataRepeaters>
                </dataGroup>
            </dataGroups>
        </dataRepeater>
    </dataRepeaters>
</dataView>
```

I am trying to convert it to something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataView name="document/aDocument" xmlns="http://component.mycompany.com/entity/ds" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <item1>1</item1>
  <item2>ABC2DEF3</item2>
  <SomeLevel1>
    <SomeLevel2>
      <someItem1>12345f</someItem1>
      <someItem2></someItem2>     
      <someItem3>11:20012:3536</someItem3>
      <someItem4>12345f</someItem4>
      <someItem5>someItem5 Data</someItem5>
      <someItem6>123456:USD</someItem6>
    </SomeLevel2>
    <SomeLevel3>
      <SomeLevel4>
        <SomeLevel5>
          <someItem7>303.149</someItem7>
          <someItem8>117:USD</someItem8>
          <someItem9>117.000000:USD</someItem9>
          <someItem10>117:USD</someItem10>
          <SomeLevel6></SomeLevel6>
        </SomeLevel5>
        <SomeLevel7>
          <someItem11>292.741</someItem11>
          <someItem12>165:USD</someItem12>
          <someItem13>165.000000:USD</someItem13>
          <someItem14>165:USD</someItem14>
        </SomeLevel7>
        <SomeLevel8>
          <someItem15>369.075</someItem15>
          <someItem16>598:USD</someItem16>
          <someItem17>598.000000:USD</someItem17>
          <SomeLevel9>
            <SomeLevel10>
              <someItem18>Some Data | ABC 123</someItem18>
              <someItem19>2</someItem19>
            </SomeLevel10>
          </SomeLevel9>
          <SomeLevel11></SomeLevel11>
        </SomeLevel8>
      </SomeLevel4>
    </SomeLevel3>
  </SomeLevel1>
</dataView>
```

So basically I am trying to take the "name" attribute and make it the XML node/tag and the value between the `<value>` node/tag and use it as the "value" for the XML node/tag.

I have tried several different parsing/writing "routines" and the below two are the two that have gotten me the closest. So I'm leaving out the other ones as they would be just "noise".

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
private Document xmlDocument;

public void convertXML() {
      xmlDocument = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader("DSExample.xml")));

      DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

      Node dsNode = xmlDocument.getDocumentElement();

      xmlDocument = docBuilder.newDocument();

      // Attempt 1:   
      doSomethingDS(dsNode); // This will convert the XML but with NO nesting - creates example output 1
      // Attempt 2:
      traverseDS(dsNode); // This will create an XML with ONLY the root dataItems - Don't know why - creates example output 2
}

public void doSomethingDS(Node node) {  
    System.out.println(node.getNodeName());
    Element xmlElement = null;

    // This will be the "root" element/node "dataView":
    if(node.getNodeName() != null && node.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("dataView")) {

      // Debugging: Print the node
      printNode(node);

      String nodeName = node.getNodeName().trim();
      rootElement = xmlDocument.createElement(nodeName);
      mPreviousElement = rootElement;

      addAllAttributesToRootElement((Element) node, rootElement);

      xmlDocument.appendChild(rootElement);
    }
    else {

        // Debugging: Print the node
        printNode(node);

        // If has "name" property - create element/node
        if(node.getAttributes() != null && node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name") != null) {
          xmlElement = createElement(xmlDocument, node);

          if(xmlElement !=null && xmlDocument.getFirstChild() != null) {
            xmlDocument.getFirstChild().appendChild(xmlElement);  
          }
        }

    }    

    NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
    for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
      Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
      if(currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        // recursively call this method for all the children which are of type Element
        doSomethingDS(currentNode);
      }
    }
} // End of doSomethingDS() 


public void traverseDS(Node parentNode) {
    // This will create an XML with ONLY the root dataItems - Don't know why.

    Element xmlElement = null;

    //****************************************************************
    // This will be the "root" element/node "dataView":
    if(parentNode.getNodeName() != null && parentNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("dataView")) {

      // Debugging: Print the node
      printNode(parentNode);

      String nodeName = parentNode.getNodeName().trim();
      rootElement = xmlDocument.createElement(nodeName);
      mPreviousElement = rootElement;

      if(!isRootNodeSet) {        
        mRootNode = parentNode;
        isRootNodeSet = true;
      }

      addAllAttributesToRootElement((Element) parentNode, rootElement);

      xmlDocument.appendChild(rootElement);

      // traverse children
      Node theNode = parentNode.getFirstChild();
      if(theNode != null) {
        theNode = theNode.getNextSibling();
      }
      else if (isRootNodeSet) {
        theNode = mRootNode.getNextSibling();
      }

      traverseDS(theNode);
    }
    else {

      // traverse all nodes that belong to the parent
      for(Node theNode = parentNode.getFirstChild(); theNode != null; theNode = theNode.getNextSibling()) {

        // Debugging: Print the node
        printNode(theNode);

        // If has "name" property - create element/node
        if(theNode.getAttributes() != null && theNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name") != null) {
          // Create new Element/Node
          xmlElement = createElement(xmlDocument, theNode);
          if(xmlElement !=null && xmlDocument.getFirstChild() != null) {
            xmlDocument.getFirstChild().appendChild(xmlElement);  
          }
          else {
            System.out.println(" not a node we wanted?");
          }
        }

        // traverse children     
        traverseDS(theNode);
      }
    }
} // End of traverseDS()
private Element createElement(Document aDoc, Node aNode) {
    Element xmlElement = null;
    String elementName = "";

    NamedNodeMap dataNodeMap = aNode.getAttributes();
    if(dataNodeMap != null && dataNodeMap.getNamedItem("name") != null) {

      elementName = dataNodeMap.getNamedItem("name").getTextContent();
      xmlElement = aDoc.createElement(elementName);

      // if node = "dataItem" - walk node to get <value> node
      // Note: some "dataItem" nodes also have a <previousValue> node - what to do with these????
      if(aNode.getNodeName() != null && aNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("dataItem")) {
        // Walk Node to get <value> node
        NodeList childNodes = aNode.getChildNodes();
        int childNodesLength = childNodes.getLength();
        for(int x = 0; x < childNodesLength; x++) {
          Node childNode = childNodes.item(x);
          if(childNode.getNodeName() != null && childNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("value")) {
            xmlElement.setTextContent(childNode.getTextContent());
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return xmlElement;
} // End of createElement()
```

Example Output 1 (created by doSomethingDS()):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<dataView xmlns="http://component.mycompany.com/entity/ds" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="document/aDocument">
    <item1>1</item1>
    <item2>ABC2DEF3</item2>
    <SomeLevel1/>
    <SomeLevel2/>
    <someItem1>12345</someItem1>
    <someItem2/>
    <someItem3>11:20012:3536</someItem3>
    <someItem4/>
    <someItem5>someItem5 Data</someItem5>
    <someItem6>123456:USD</someItem6>
    <SomeLevel3/>
    <SomeLevel4/>
    <SomeLevel5/>
    <someItem6>303.149</someItem6>
    <someItem7>117:USD</someItem7>
    <someItem8>117.000000:USD</someItem8>
    <someItem9>117:USD</someItem9>
    <SomeLevel6/>
    <SomeLevel7/>
    <someItem10>292.741</someItem10>
    <someItem11>165:USD</someItem11>
    <someItem12>165.000000:USD</someItem12>
    <someItem13>165:USD</someItem13>
    <SomeLevel8/>
    <someItem14>369.075</someItem14>
    <someItem15>598:USD</someItem15>
    <someItem16>598.000000:USD</someItem16>
    <SomeLevel9/>
    <SomeLevel10/>
    <someItem17>Some Data | ABC 123</someItem17>
    <someItem18>2</someItem18>
    <SomeLevel11/>
</dataView>
```

Example Output 2 (Created by traverseDS()):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<dataView xmlns="http://component.mycompany.com/entity/ds" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="document/aDocument">
    <item1>1</item1>
    <item2>ABC2DEF3</item2>
</dataView>
```

Now here is that catch.... What I get is dynamic I could get a Mac truck one time and a Toyota the next or a mixture of the two. And the size of the XML I get could be small or large. So it's hard to just use XPath or directly go after specific elements as I don't know what I'll get. This is why I'm basically walking/traversing the DOM a node at a time to extract out just what is useable.

So my question is:
What am I doing wrong in my parsing/writing of the XML file to not get it to look like what I'm trying to get it to look like?

Comment: Have you considered some XSLT transformation to do that job?

Comment: It seems as if you're always appending to the `dataView` element in `doSomethingDS()` since you're always calling `xmlDocument.getFirstChild().appendChild(xmlElement)`. I'd guess you need to keep track of the element you're traversing into and append the new elements to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is (almost) trivially easy with XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ds="http://component.mycompany.com/entity/ds" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://component.mycompany.com/entity/ds" 
>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="ds:dataView" priority="1">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ds:*[@name]">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied do your input, gives you:

```
<dataView xmlns="http://component.mycompany.com/entity/ds" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <item1>1</item1>
  <item2>ABC2DEF3</item2>
  <SomeLevel1>
    <SomeLevel2>
      <someItem1>12345</someItem1>
      <someItem2 />
      <someItem3>11:20012:3536</someItem3>
      <someItem4 />
      <someItem5>someItem5 Data</someItem5>
      <someItem6>123456:USD</someItem6>
    </SomeLevel2>
    <SomeLevel3>
      <SomeLevel4>
        <SomeLevel5>
          <someItem6>303.149</someItem6>
          <someItem7>117:USD</someItem7>
          <someItem8>117.000000:USD</someItem8>
          <someItem9>117:USD</someItem9>
          <SomeLevel6 />
        </SomeLevel5>
        <SomeLevel7>
          <someItem10>292.741</someItem10>
          <someItem11>165:USD</someItem11>
          <someItem12>165.000000:USD</someItem12>
          <someItem13>165:USD</someItem13>
        </SomeLevel7>
        <SomeLevel8>
          <someItem14>369.075</someItem14>
          <someItem15>598:USD</someItem15>
          <someItem16>598.000000:USD</someItem16>
          <SomeLevel9>
            <SomeLevel10>
              <someItem17>Some Data | ABC 123</someItem17>
              <someItem18>2</someItem18>
            </SomeLevel10>
          </SomeLevel9>
          <SomeLevel10 />
        </SomeLevel8>
      </SomeLevel4>
    </SomeLevel3>
  </SomeLevel1>
</dataView>
```

Notes:

Having numbered element names (`someItem1` thru `someItem6`) will come back and bite you, eventually. XML elements have a natural order (or you can have a "number" attribute), putting a counter into the name is bad and wrong. Take my advice and don't do that <sup>(*)</sup>.

To understand the solution here's a quick breakdown:

- XSLT processors run XML nodes through templates by finding the best match for the XML node at hand.
- The process starts with the root node.
- Since there is no template explicitly matching the root node (`<xsl:template match="/">`), a default rule kicks in: Output nothing, but find templates for the child nodes.
- The first (and only) child node is the document element (`<ds:dataView>`).
- The template #1 matches that node, tells the processor to copy it and process its children (`<xsl:apply-templates />`).
- Every element that has a `@name` is matched by template #2, which outputs an element with that name and again processes its children.
- Every other element (like those `<value>` nodes) is - in the absence of any matching template - processed according to the mentioned default rule.
- Text nodes are matched by template #3, which outputs their trimmed value.

Additional notes:

- The expression in curly braces is called an *attribute value template*.
- The template `priority="1"` makes sure that this template is selected for the `<ds:dataView>` element, because the other one would match as well.
- Your result document still is in the `"http://component.mycompany.com/entity/ds"`. This might or might not be correct. I suspect it's not correct, technically speaking, but you decide.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> `<xsl:element name="{translate(@name, '0123456789', '')}"` would be one variant to lose the counters.

Comment: Thank you - I'll take a look at XSLT for this job.
Note: the "number elements" were only created to "scrub" the real names that were in there to "hide' the information that was really there (proprietary).

Comment: As long as you have thought it through... :)

Comment: For some reason using XSLT I don't get any of the XML tags.

Output I get:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
1ABC2DEF31234511:20012:3536someItem5 Data123456:USD303.149117:USD117.000000:USD117:USD292.741165:USD165.000000:USD165:USD369.075598:USD598.000000:USDSome Data | ABC 1232

Comment: Very likely a namespace problem. double check all namespace declarations, URIs and prefixes.

Comment: It was a namespace issue. :(

Comment: Well, *that* was easy. :) Let me guess. Your company isn't actually called "mycompany". ;)

Answer (score 0):

XSLT has been created exactly for a task like that. As long as your Source-XML (unconventional xml) is well-formed (correct xml-syntax) so that it can be read by a standard xml-parser like DOM, you can use that.

It works like so: You create a xsl-template file that contains a declerative description how the source  xml should be transformed into another format. The transformation itself is done by a XSL-Transformer.
The xsl is also an xml-format, so it should be quit easy readable, as long as the transformation is not too complex.

Here is explained how that can be implemented:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html